# TypeError: Cannot read property 'instanceIdentifier' of undefined (FirebaseStorage)

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload some files to Firebase Storage using dart web. But the declaration of the reference fails. Here the code when the reference is declared:

```
Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('test');
```

The index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

The pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
    firebase_storage: ^8.0.3
```

And finally this is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'instanceIdentifier' of undefined
at _.ft [as instanceFactory] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-storage.js:1:39384)
at I.getOrInitializeService (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js:1:8586)
at I.getImmediate (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js:1:6577)
at G._getService (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js:1:14805)
at G.n.type.a.<computed> [as storage] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js:1:17592)
at Object.e [as storage] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js:1:17415)
at Object.getStorageInstance (http://localhost:36593/packages/firebase_storage_web/src/interop/storage.dart.lib.js:777:75)
at new firebase_storage_web.FirebaseStorageWeb.new (http://localhost:36593/packages/firebase_storage_web/src/reference_web.dart.lib.js:321:33)
at firebase_storage_web.FirebaseStorageWeb._nullInstance.delegateFor (http://localhost:36593/packages/firebase_storage_web/src/reference_web.dart.lib.js:267:14)
at Function.instanceFor (http://localhost:36593/packages/firebase_storage_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_task_snapshot.dart.lib.js:970:83)
at firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.__.get [_delegate] (http://localhost:36593/packages/firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart.lib.js:95:120)
at firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.__.ref (http://localhost:36593/packages/firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart.lib.js:135:58)
at add_connector._AddConnectorState.new.onPressedSendButton (http://localhost:36593/packages/client_doc_collector/screens/home/main_section/connectors/add_connector/add_connector.dart.lib.js:1000:76)
at onPressedSendButton.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:36593/dart_sdk.js:39051:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:36593/dart_sdk.js:39082:7)
at add_connector._AddConnectorState.new.onPressedSendButton (http://localhost:36593/packages/client_doc_collector/screens/home/main_section/connectors/add_connector/add_connector.dart.lib.js:996:20)
at ink_well._InkResponseState.new.[_handleTap] (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/material/icon_button.dart.lib.js:50511:42)
at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.invokeCallback (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.lib.js:203:18)
at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleTapUp (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:417:40)
at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.[_checkUp] (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:223:12)
at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.acceptGesture (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:199:23)
at arena.GestureArenaManager.new.sweep (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart.lib.js:222:31)
at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleEvent (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:335:27)
at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:314:24)
at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:6087:13)
at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerEventImmediately] (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:285:14)
at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handlePointerEvent (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:258:43)
at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_flushPointerEventQueue] (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:247:14)
at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerDataPacket] (http://localhost:36593/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:237:65)
at Object.invoke1 (http://localhost:36593/dart_sdk.js:183786:7)
at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.invokeOnPointerDataPacket (http://localhost:36593/dart_sdk.js:164268:15)
at _engine.PointerBinding.__.[_onPointerData] (http://localhost:36593/dart_sdk.js:164902:49)
at http://localhost:36593/dart_sdk.js:165359:28
at http://localhost:36593/dart_sdk.js:165312:16
at http://localhost:36593/dart_sdk.js:165006:11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using this Firebase Resource v8.3.1:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

I got the same error on trying to use the firebase storage SDK:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'instanceIdentifier' of undefined
```

I changed the firebase storage script resource version to 8.1.2:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

right now, the error doesn't appear anymore.

my suggestion is:
if you don't have another dependencies, Try to change the 8.3.1 to 8.1.2 version of firebase storage SDK. worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

Path in reference is required in `...instance.ref()`

Check official [flutterfire storage reference docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#references).